# Floating-point number operations in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying write a function that takes as input a list of floating point numbers
and returns a list in which all negative numbers are removed from the input list and then all resulting positive numbers are negated.

```
let f (mylist: float list) : float list = 
    let f1 = List.filter (fun x -> x < 0.0) mylist in
        List.map (fun x -> (-x*1.0)) f1
```

I have a type error:

```
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type int
```

Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't quite make sense. You have `let f1 = ... in` but then have an expression that doesn't have `f1` but instead has some unknown expression `g1a`. In any event -- *what* is throwing an error? The definition of `f` or the way you are using it? Please give a [mcve]. This seems to be a fragment of a larger definition.

Comment: @JohnColeman I fixed that typo. The error message is in the original post. Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type int

Comment: @JohnColeman No. That is it.  A simple problem! A tiny simple problem that has a type error which I cannot figured out by myself.

Comment: for your curiosity  : a version using ~-. operator and some tips to write your function in a more compact way : let f l = List.(l |> filter ((>) 0.) |> map (( *.) ~-.1.));;

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.
For the last time, to negate a floating-point number, the appropriate operator is:

```
(-.x)
```

Comment: FWIW, `-.` is the floating subtraction operator. But as in most languages it can be used to negate floating values. There is also a specific floating unary minus operator `~-.` (believe it or not).